# Proper use of CommandLineToArgvW?

Tags: c++, winapi

When parsing the command line arguments of a process whose path contains a space, the path is split up into multiple pieces by CommandLineToArgvW.

There exists a folder on all Windows' C: drives called "Program Files."

...wat

The MSDN page mentions nothing about this being a problem.  Am I just using the function wrong?  How am I supposed to predict what words are part of the path otherwise?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`CommandLineToArgvW` splits the line on spaces - if you need an argument (or the program name) to contain spaces you need to surround it with quotation marks.

- `C:\Program Files` - argv[0] = *C:\Program*, argv[1] = *Files*
- `"C:\Program Files"` - argv[0] = *C:\Program Files*

Note that you can get the file path of your process using `GetModuleFileName` - you can do this to determine whether the path contains a space, and insert the quotes in the command line if needed before parsing it.

Comment: This is all well and good, but how do I know where to place the quotations if I don't know where the path ends in the first place?

Comment: Oh.  Guess I'll go do that.  (I also get a bunch of environment variables for some reason, how do I deal with those?)

Comment: `ExpandEnvironmentStrings`.

Comment: Okay, I must be going insane.  All of a sudden lpCmdLine is just some empty string, it was working just fine before and I made no changes to the project settings or preprocessor macros...

Comment: Where did it come from? If you're using the string passed into `WinMain` you're better off using the `GetCommandLine` function instead.

Comment: Should I still use WinMain's hInstance, or is that unreliable too?

Comment: Er... it's still empty.  What the hell man?  I swear I didn't change anything.

Comment: You'll probably need to post some code in another question for proper help with this issue.

Comment: Actually I fixed it by restarting.  I can't explain why this has anything to do with it, but my program crashed in a way I haven't seen before and Windows brought up a dialog about reporting errors to the developer, which is when it stopped working.